# How to group together 3D points that are all within a distance of each other

Tags: c++, 3d, coordinates

So I have a list of 3D points and I want to group together points that are within 1 unit or less from each other. So here's an example of what I'm talking about (I'll use 2D points for the example),

Say we have point 1: (0,0) and point 2: (0,1) which are 1 distance from each other. The program will store both in a vector. Now here's a third point (0,2). This point is 1 distance from point 2 but not from point 1 but the program will still store it since it is within 1 distance from at least 1 point in the vector.

So I want to gather 3D points in "blobs" and everything that is 1 unit or less from this "blob" will be added onto the "blob"

I've tried so many different functions these past few days, tried recursion but always crashes and nested tons of forloops but I can't make this work.

Here's my code (I added in comments next to the code to make it easier to understand)

```
void combinePoints(vector<Point>& allPoints, vector< vector<Cavity> >& allPointBlobs, vector<Point>& tempBlob)
{
     float check;
     if(allPoints.size() != 0) //if statement to stop recursion once all the points from "allPoints" vector is checked and removed
     {
         for(int i = 0; i < allPoints.size(); i++) //3d distance formula checking first point with all other points
         {
             check = sqrt((allPoints[0].getX() - allPoints[i].getX()) * (allPoints[0].getX() - allPoints[i].getX()) + 
             (allPoints[0].getY() - allPoints[i].getY()) * (allPoints[0].getY() - allPoints[i].getY()) + 
             (allPoints[0].getZ() - allPoints[i].getZ()) * (allPoints[0].getZ() - allPoints[i].getZ())); 
             if ((check <= 1.000) && (check != 0 )) //once a point is found that is 1 distance or less, it is added to tempBlob vector and removed from allPoints
                     {
                               tempBlob.push_back(allPoints[0]);
                               tempBlob.push_back(allPoints[i]);
                               allPoints.erase(allPoints.begin() + i);
                               allPoints.erase(connollyPoints.begin());
                               break;
                     }
         }
         if(check > 1.000) //However, if no points are nearby, then tempBlob is finished finding all nearby points and is added to a vector and cleared so it can start finding another blob.
         {
                  allPointBlobs.push_back(tempBlob);
                  tempBlob.clear();
                  cout << "Blob Done" << endl;
                  combinePoints(allPoints, allPointBlobs, tempBlob);
         }
         else
         {
         combinePoints2(allPoints, allPointBlobs, tempBlob);
         }
     }
}
void combinePoints2(vector<Point>& allPoints, vector< vector<Point> >& allPointBlobs, vector<Point>& tempBlob) //combinePoints2 is almost the same as the first one, except I changed the first part where it doesnt have to initiate a vector with first two points. This function will then check all points in the temporary blob against all other points and find ones that are 1 distance or less
{
     cout << tempBlob.size() << endl; //I use this just to check if function is working
     float check = 0;
     if(allPoints.size() != 0)
     {
         for(int j = 0; j < tempBlob.size(); j++)
         {
             for(int k = 0; k < allPoints.size(); k++)
             {
                 check = sqrt((tempBlob[j].getX() - allPoints[k].getX()) * (tempBlob[j].getX() - allPoints[k].getX()) + 
                 (tempBlob[j].getY() - allPoints[k].getY()) * (tempBlob[j].getY() - allPoints[k].getY()) + 
                 (tempBlob[j].getZ() - allPoints[k].getZ()) * (tempBlob[j].getZ() - allPoints[k].getZ())); 
                 if ((check <= 1.000) && (check != 0 ))
                     {  
                               tempBlob.push_back(allPoints[k]);  
                              allPoints.erase(allPoints.begin() + k);
                               break;    
                     }
             }
             if ((check <= 1.000) && (check != 0 ))
             {
                 break;
             }
         }
         if(check > 1.000)
         {
                  allPointBlobs.push_back(tempBlob);
                  tempBlob.clear();
                  cout << "Blob Done" << endl;
                  combinePoints(allPoints, allPointBlobs, tempBlob);
         }
         else
         {
         combinePoints2(allPoints, allPointBlobs, tempBlob);
         }
     }
}
```

I use all the breaks because when a point is deleted from allPoints, it messes up the forloops since I'm using .size() for the amount of times it runs. This makes the program really slow since it has to keep reinitiating the function when it finds 1 point. I'm hoping someone can help me find a simpler way to do this.

I've made many other functions but they crash, this is the only one that is working so far (or at least i hope its working lol, it just doesnt crash which is a good sign).

Comment: Please try adding code example of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a function that gets two points as arguments and determines if they are within a certain distance or use a class "Point" with a method that checks if a point passed as argument is within distance x of this point.
2. Store all points within distance of 1 in a simple vector to represent your "blob".

A simple naive class could look like this:

```
class Point{

public:

bool withinDistance(const Point& other) const;   
void addProxyPoint(const Point& other);   

private:

double x_cord, y_cord, ...;
std::vector<Point> proximities;
};
```

Although you can do this in several other ways, especially if you don't want to store the blob on the point object itself. 
Or you can write a method that checks if a point is within distance and also adds it to your blob vector.
Your choice of course.

Comment: I have a function that checks if 2 points are within 1 distance of each other (I just use the distance formula for 3 dimensions) and I know how to add the nearby points (within 1 distance) of 1 point to a vector but I'm having trouble stemming further. My program messes up and crashes when I add in the forloops. I'm working with thousands of 3D points (currently 9000) so my program needs to be fast too. I'll post up my code with some comments to make it easier to read.